# How to Not Strip Debug Symbols in Xcode 9

Tags: macos, xcode9, debug-symbols, symbolicate, dsym

Ever since Xcode 9, I've been having issues symbolicating crash logs for my OS X application. Note, I'm not distributing through the App Store, so these are user supplied logs that I've been symbolicating with MacSymbolicator. I've decided it's not worth the headache and want to set Xcode to no longer strip debug symbols.

Surprisingly, I haven't been able to accomplish this. I seem to remember enabling Strip Debug Symbols in the Build Settings, so I thought it would be a simple matter of disabling this.  No luck though. I've played around with various combinations of build settings in Xcode 9 (Strip Debug Symbols on Copy, Strip Swift Symbols, Generate Debug Symbols, Debug Information Format, ...) and still no luck. I'm probably missing something trivial, but can someone please point me in the right direction for the correct build settings to create user supplied crash logs that do not need to be symbolicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dsymutil` manually

https://github.com/Sunbreak/cli-breakpad.trial#dump-info-for-cli-breakpad

```sh
$ dsymutil ./build/cli-breakpad -o cli-breakpad.dSYM
...
```